# How can I scrape data from LinkedIn without using any api

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, linkedin-api

If you view the source of any LinkedIn profile then you can see information in this form

```
 &quotfirstName&quot&quotDanish&quot&quot
```

- I don't know how to get this data
- Here the first name is Danish
- How can I get this record using jQuery or Javascript if I send `GET` request using jQuery on user links and get all the HTML, is it possible? or any solution for this problem

Comment: Google Selenium

Comment: @ThomasCook is right, or you can also explore using libraries like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't. You will be breaking their Terms. User their API.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibition-of-scraping-software?lang=en